# Cpu usage using Pdh Lib always showing 0 (OR)100%

Tags: cpu-usage

This is the code I am trying..

```
#include "TCHAR.h"
#include "pdh.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

static PDH_HQUERY cpuQuery;
static PDH_HCOUNTER cpuTotal;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PdhOpenQuery(NULL, NULL, &cpuQuery);
    PdhAddCounter(cpuQuery, L"\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", NULL, &cpuTotal);
    PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE counterVal;
    PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
    PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
    PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(cpuTotal, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE, NULL, &counterVal);
    cout << counterVal.doubleValue;
    getchar();
}
```

Machine details: Windows 8.1
Help me, It's always showing 0 or 100.

Comment: How to find the other computers (which are in same network) CPU usage from my computer using pdh lib??

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving the **% Processor Time**, there must be a delay between sample collections

We need to make at least few 100 milliseconds delay between PdhCollectQueryData calls.

```
PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
```

This will fix the issue.
Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/262938